# Django Ajax not entrering in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

When i press the link the program should go to the ajax function to update the database without reloading the page.
the problem is when the link is pressed doesnt enter in the JS function (doesnt show the alert)

```
 <a href="#" onclick="xpto2()" >Remind later</a>
<script>    
function xpto2(){
     alert("hello");
     $.ajax({
        url: 'update-notify-status-noshow',
        data: { postdata1: {{ n.id }} }, 
        dataType: 'html', 
        type: 'get', )
        success: function(output) {
        alert(output); 
        }
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: doesn't show either alert? What errors are thrown in console? Is function in global scope? Some basic troubleshooting information would help. If you don't know how...do some research on using browser dev tools and console

Comment: doenst sohw the alert and the errors shown in the console are:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' 
ReferenceError: xpto is not defined

Comment: Use a code linter (in IDE or online) to check your syntax errors. Those should never be brought here as questions when there are numerous tools available to find them. If the syntax error is in the ajax response that is another problem altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your xpto2 function. There are syntax errors. This should be something like this.

```
<script>    
        function xpto2() {
           alert("hello");
           $.ajax({
            url: 'update-notify-status-noshow',
            data: { postdata1: {{ n.id }} },
            dataType: 'html', 
            type: 'get',

            success: function(output) {
                alert(output); 
            }
        });
       }
   </script>
```

Make sure jQuery is present.

Keep browser console opened for better insights.

Here's a full template to try.

#### updates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>    
        function xpto2() {
           alert("hello");
           $.ajax({
            url: 'update-notify-status-noshow',
            data: { postdata1: {{ n.id }} },
            dataType: 'html', 
            type: 'get',

            success: function(output) {
                alert(output); 
            }
        });
           }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="xpto2()" >Remind later</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the errors are:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' 
ReferenceError: xpto2() is not defined

Comment: Same error... and i imported that library. one thing that ive notice, was when i dont have the ajax, only the alert, it works. with the ajax function say ReferenceError: xpto2() is not defined

Comment: Are you including two versions of jQuery or xpto2 function?

Comment: One, clicked on the link and downloaded the jquery library